# MDX query is reporting a unique row for each instance rather then rolling the data into one row where multiple column details apply

Tags: mdx, azure-data-factory, sap-bw

When I use the below MDX query on Azure Data factory Pipeline which is used to transfer data from SAP BW to Azure:

```
    SELECT { [Measures].[00O2TN6100F25XV2PK2K7KLIP] } ON COLUMNS,
    NON EMPTY { [ZBW_Country].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS,                                                     [ZBW_Province].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS,                                                                 [ZBW_City].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS } ON ROWS
    FROM ZCO_MP01/YCO_MP01_Q006_V2_RS1
    WHERE [0CALYEAR].[2019]
```

My table looks like:

```
Country    Province  City     Sales
Canada                         13.12
           ON                  13.12   
                     Toronto   13.12
```

So I tried redefining it to below query:

```
    SELECT {[Measures].[00O2TN6100F25XV2PK2K7KLIP] }ON 0,
    NON EMPTY CROSSJOIN(CROSSJOIN(DISTINCT([ZBW_Country].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS), DISTINCT([ZBW_Province].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS)), DISTINCT([ZBW_City].[LEVEL01].MEMBERS)) PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [ZBW_MATNR].[2ZBW_MATNR] ON 1
    FROM [ZCO_MP01/YCO_MP01]
```

This query works for me, it solves the issue and now I receive the data like this

```
Country    Province  City     Sales
Canada      ON       Toronto   13.12
```

But when I bring in rest of the fields (I have almost 55 fields) then my Azure pipeline keeps on running and I cannot see it neither working nor aborting.

Can anyone please help me modifying this query to address the above issue without using cross join? I suspect my query is making the system very slow to process.

FYI: I'm new to MDX and I did enabled tracing on Microsoft Power Bi and then used the MDX query from its logs to draft the above query)

Comment: what exactly is it that you are trying to achive in MDX , what is your requirement?

Comment: If you can see the first table that I have mentioned, I have each value in a separate row. So I'm basically trying to get rid of this issue. I have figured it out and I was able to get it right. But the query I was using is expensive so I'm trying to find if there is any other way to solve this issue..